# Can the C offsetof() macro be applied to unions?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

It's often assumed that offsetof() can be applied to unions (you can even find such use in several questions here at SO), but, however, it seems like all the C specifications from C90 to nowadays only say the offsetof() macro supports structs. I was now taking a look at the "Modern C" book by Jens Gustedt, and table 4.3 specifies "struct" as the type of the first argument to offsetof().

So,... are unions officially supported by offsetof(), or not?

Comment: What is the point? Every field in `union` is at offset `0` anyway.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Nope. Unions can contain anonymous structures. Offsets of members within this struct can be non-zero

Comment: @tstanisl Right... Anyway, the standard is talking about "structure" as a parameter, but the "typical" implementation of the macro can very well work with unions.

Comment: A `union` is only a single storage large enough to hold any of the specified types and holds the one last assigned. `offsetof()` would be meaningless there.

Comment: @tstanisl if you apply that to the nested struct then it's the struc that matters, not the parent union. They're not at the same level

Comment: @phuclv, No. Members of a nested anonymous union are considered the members of the parent aggregate. See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p13

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a defect in the C spec, up until C2x. This was brought up in a defect report for the C11 spec [DR 496](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2396.htm#dr_496), which was resolved in C2x.

From the [C11 spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section §7.19 paragraph 3, the definition for `offsetof`:

> `offsetof(type, member-designator)`
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression that has type `size_t`, the value of which is the offset in bytes, to the structure member (designated by *member-designator*), from the beginning of its structure (designated by *type*). The type and member designator shall be such that given
>
> `static type t;`
>
> then the expression `&(t.member-designator)` evaluates to an address constant. (If the specified member is a bit-field, the behavior is undefined.)

The *type* argument is described as a "structure member", yet the expression `&(t.member-designator)` is also well-defined for union types (§6.7.2.1 paragraph 16). This gave rise to ambiguity for compiler authors, so most have chosen to allow `offsetof` on unions.

In the C2x spec this is reworded (bold emphasis mine):

> `offsetof(type, member-designator)`
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression that has type `size_t`, the value of which is the offset in bytes, to the **subobject** (designated by *member-designator*), from the beginning of **any object of type *type***. The type and member designator shall be such that given
>
> `static type t;`
>
> then the expression `&(t.member-designator)` evaluates to an address constant. **If the specified *type* defines a new type** or if the specified member is a bit-field, the behavior is undefined.

With the changes being:

- "structure member" -> "subobject"
- "beginning of its structure" -> "beginning of any object of type *type*"
- using `offsetof` on new type declarations is undefined behavior

---

To answer the question of "can `offsetof` be applied to unions":

- In C2x, yes
- In older versions, likely also yes, given many compilers support it

Comment: Great answer and citation. At least compiler writers have certainty now with all ambiguity removed. While now explicitly supported for any type with subobjects, for `union` it ends up being "turtles all the way down". Zero is zero is zero. So in application for unions it seems a little "ho hum".